# Java: min method for array with random ints and inputted count

Tags: java, arrays, random, statistics, minimum

The full assignment was to create a number of methods, e.g. getMode and getAverage, to compute stats for an array with randomly-generated numbers and user-inputted ceiling max, floor min, and sample size. All of my other methods seem to work, but every time I try returning the *populated set*'s min value, I get 0--even if the inputted min was something higher.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Stats extends Main
{
int sampleSize;
double count;
double ave;
double sum;
int mode;
int evenCount;
int oddCount;
int countMatching;
int counter;
int target;
int match;

//Method: return the sample set's max value
public int getMax(int sampleSize, int[] data)
{
    int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    max = data[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] > max)
            max = data[i];
    }
    return max;
}
//Method: return the min value
public int getMin(int sampleSize, int[] data)
{
    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    min = data[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] < min)
            min = data[i];
    }
    return min;
...
```

And the main program:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int stats;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Stats Program!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter sample size: ");
    int sampleSize = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("What is the sample set's minimum? ");
    int min = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("What is the sample set's maximum? ");
    int max = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    Stats g = new Stats();
    System.out.println("Main Menu");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("1) Get max value");
    System.out.println("2) Get min value");
    System.out.println("3) Get the mean");
    System.out.println("4) Get the mode");
    System.out.println("5) Get the count of even numbers");
    System.out.println("6) Get the count of odd numbers");
    System.out.println("7) Display the sample set");
    System.out.println("8) Return the count of numbers in the sample set  that match the input parameter");
    System.out.println("9) Exit");
    System.out.println();
    stats = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Constructor: use an RNG to generate sampleSize integers between        minValue and maxValue. Store the numbers in an array named 'data'.
    int[] data = new int[sampleSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            data[i] = rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min);
        }

    while (stats != 9)
    {
        if (stats == 1)
        {
            g.getMax(sampleSize, data);
            System.out.println("Max is: " + g.getMax(sampleSize, data));
            System.out.println();
        }
        else if (stats == 2)
        {
            g.getMin(sampleSize, data);
            System.out.println("Min is: " + g.getMin(sampleSize, data));
            System.out.println();
        }
        ...
```

Any idea why my program isn't returning appropriate min values (equal to or above what the user inputs)? The max seems to come out fine--sometimes it's below the user's inputted max, and most often it's equal. I've looked at other questions re. min/max and arrays with random numbers, but haven't been able to apply their solutions to my own problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does `Stats` extend `Main` in the first place? Doesn't make any sense in my opinion. Your code snippet looks fine however I would suggest some improvements, just for the look ;) assign `int min` right away to `data[0]`, start your loop with `i = 1` as the the first value has already been used. The `sampleSize` variable is redundant, use `data.length` property instead. And finally replace the if evaluation in the for-loop with `min = Math.min(min, data[i])`. But generally speaking, your code should work fine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this part of your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        data[i] = rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min);
    }
```

First wrong thing is that you create a new random number generator *in each iteration*. You should create it before the loop and just use it in the loop.

But that's the less important issue. The more important one is the way you run `rand.nextInt()`. Suppose your `min` is 3 and your `max` is 7. Then `(max - min + 1) + min` gives you 8. And this means you are calling `rand.nextInt(8)`, which will give you a number such that 0 ≤ number < 8.

The method [`Random.nextInt(int n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) gives you back a number such that 0 ≤ number < n. So if you want a number such that 3 ≤ number < 8, you'll need it to give you something between 0 and 5, and add that to 3. This means:

```
rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

It looks *almost* like what you wrote, but the extra pair of parentheses made all the difference. You can't just stick parentheses anywhere. The first parenthesis after the name of a method defines that method's parameters, and in your case, it caused the `+ min` to become part of the parameter to `nextInt`.

---

One more thing: your class should *not* extend `Main`. They are not related in any way, your `Stats` is not a kind of `Main`, right?

Comment: Re. "Then (max - min + 1) + min gives you 8. And this means you are calling rand.nextInt(8), which will give you a number such that 0 ≤ number < 8.": How should my rand.nextInt() parenthetical read? Our instructor said it should simply be what I had it as, but I now get why that doesn't work.

Using your example, how would I make it so that the number is 3 ≤ number < 8?

Comment: @SurajSood I have edited my answer to explain the proper use of `nextInt()`.

Comment: Hallelujah! My program is now completely functional. Many thanks for explaining the consequences of superfluous parentheses. A bit amused that that turned out to be the source of my two week-long headache.

Answer (score 0):

Your `min` method seems to work well, maybe there is no number in your array that is less than 0.

This answer is not exactly to make your actual method work but is just a suggestion for a much easier way to do this.

You could use `Collections` and `Commons Lang` to find the min/max of an array and to convert a primitive array to a List.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

public class tst {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 23, 43, 2, 4, 5, 5, 1, 2, 3};

        List lst = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(arr));

        System.out.println(Collections.min(lst));
        System.out.println(Collections.max(lst));
    }
}
```

This will output `min:1` and `max:43`.

This is a good solution to consider if you are not forced to use primitive arrays and do everything by yourself.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change you random nextInt function on how you get the random value.
it should be

```
data[i] = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

not `data[i] = rand.nextInt((max - min + 1) + min);`